# Executing code after Response.End()

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am generating an excel file download on button click. After the excel is downloaded, the response is being stopped and ended. Could you please suggest how I can prevent stopping such that user can download as many times as he requires without a page refresh?

```
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = 
  "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
Response.AddHeader
(
  "content-disposition", 
  "attachment;  filename=PFMWarehouseList_" 
  + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") + ".xlsx"
);

Response.BinaryWrite(pck.GetAsByteArray());

//HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
Response.End();
```

Comment: may be start the download in a new page..

Comment: can you show how you implement that button click, or what did you tried?

Comment: If you would like to avoid postbacks, I would suggest javascript.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Do you want the user to get more than one file on download with one button click, or do you want him to be able to continue clicking (your code should do that, it shouldn't cause a page refresh, although obviously you cannot use `/` in a file name)?

Comment: I am downloading the file upon button click, so now when I try to click for the second time again for downloading as the request is ended the code is being stopped. Is there any way that I could make the button to work even after downloading for further downloads

Answer (score 0):

```
string Url = "FullPatchYourFile";
FileInfo file = new FileInfo(Url);

try
{
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=YourFileName");
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/zip"); 
    Response.ContentType = ".zip"; //YourExtensionFile
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());
    Response.WriteFile(file.FullName);
    Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);
    Response.End();
}
finally
{
    Your instructions after response.end();
}
```

Comment: While this may anser the question, please also provide a short explanation what your code does and why it solves the initial problem. Don't just drop some lines of code without any comment.